# Are the elements of the adjoint represetnation normal operators

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given a Lie group $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ on has the adjoint action of each $g\in G$ given by $Ad_g(\mathfrak{g})$.

Is $Ad_g: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$ a normal operator always? It is normal in the case of $G=SU(n)$?

Comment: Normality is a condition that only makes sense with respect to a choice of inner product. In general there isn't a natural choice of inner product on $\mathfrak{g}$. (In the semisimple case you can take the Killing form; is this what you mean?)

Comment: Ok, I see, good point. Yes, let's consider the case of the killing form.

Comment: In that case, the answer is yes. In fact the adjoint action is skew-adjoint with respect to the Killing form. This is equivalent to the fact that the Killing form is invariant.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. That's actually quite obvious now you pointed it out. Thanks.